# convert SQLite3 query tuple to dict using database column names as dictionary keys

Tags: python

I want to make a dict from a tuple result of a SQLite3 query, I already made it but I feel that there is a lot of improvement opportunity to maybe use the table headers instead the declared dictionary keys that I used, here is my code:

```
def tup_to_dict(query):
contacts = []
contact = {
    "IG": None,
    "name": None,
    "mail": None,
    "phone": None,
    "link": None
}
for row in query:
    tmp_dict = contact.copy()
    for index, key in enumerate(contact):
        tmp_dict[key] = row[index]
    contacts.append(tmp_dict)
return contacts

conn = sqlite3.connect('instagram.db')
c = conn.cursor()
contacts = tup_to_dict(c.execute("SELECT * FROM leads").fetchall())

print(contacts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in [sqlite3.Row()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#accessing-columns-by-name-instead-of-by-index)  class designed to be used as row factory

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('instagram.db')

conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
contacts = c.execute("SELECT * FROM leads").fetchall()
for contact in contacts:
    assert contact[0] == contact["IG"]
    assert contact[1] == contact["name"]
    assert contact[2] == contact["mail"]
    assert contact[3] == contact["phone"]
    assert contact[4] == contact["link"]
```